# Declare a variable in pig through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, apache-pig

I have a use case like below.

```
declare filterAlias "if [[ $exeteral_variable == true ]]; then echo A; else echo B; fi"

A = FOREACH loadData GENERATE a, b, c, d;
B = FILTER loadData BY (a==‘xyz’);

C = foreach $filterAlias generate a,b,c,d;
```

I need to consider either **A** or **B** based on the condition which am trying to execute in the shell script. But shell script `"if [[ $1 == true ]]; then echo A; else echo B; fi"` is failing to execute within the quote.

Is there any way to address this issue?

Comment: if you really need to use true just `if (( $exeteral_variable )); ...` then what do you mean `failing`?

Comment: not quite understood, within ehich quotes? I see only `xyz`

Comment: @ Малъ Скрылевъ, I agree with you. The problem is not that one. the problem is, any output within the quotes considered as command. Hence am unable to get the output either A or B from, `if [[ $exeteral_variable == true ]]; then echo A; else echo B; fi`.   Please execute this from command line. <br> exeteral_variable=true;  `if (($exeteral_variable)); then echo A; else echo B; fi`

Comment: in first case I got A, and second B

Comment: @ Малъ Скрылевъ,thank you for helping. it works as you told when we execute it without backtick. But these things need to execute between backtick/quote.  Because, the output need to assign to another variable in pig script. just like                                             **`declare filterAlias <backtick>if [[ $exeteral_variable == true ]]; then echo A; else echo B; fi<backtick>`**

Comment: `another variable in pig script` -> please show how?

Comment: what does mean the line `foreach $filterAlias generate a,b,c,d;`?

Comment: What do you mean by failing to execute? What error does it give?